# Accessing R6 class variable when variable name is not known advance?

Tags: r, class, r6

Here's a simple code, which illustrates what I'd like to achieve:

```
require(R6)
cTest <- R6Class(
  "CTest", 
  public = list(
    a = 10, b=20, c=30,
    printX = function(x) {
      print(self[x])
    }
  )
) #"CTest"

myClass <- cTest$new(); 
for (x in c("a","b", "c"))
   myClass$printX("a")
```

And it does not work.  Error message:

```
"Error in self[x] : object of type 'environment' is not subsettable"
```

For comparison, the similar task for lists/data.frames works:

```
for (x in c("mpg","cyl", "hp"))
   print(mtcars[x])
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work fine if you use double-bracket indexing (i.e., `print(self[[x]])`).  The problem is that in general single-bracket indexing tries to extract a *subset* of the original object; in contrast double-bracket indexing extracts an *element* of the original object. For example, if `L` is a list of numbers, `L[x]` is a sub-list, while `L[[x]]` is a number.  From Hadley Wickham on twitter:

[image]

Comment: I clarified the question - it's about good programming practices by writing data-agnostic codes, where you never hard code variable names (so that you can use your code inside loop or function). 
   Please run the first code snippet of the question (it will generate error), then the second snippet, (it works fine).